# Word to explain "mapping the unseen to the seen" (i.e. infrared light to visible light)

Tags: single-word-requests, science, concept

There is a popular misconception that sound can travel through space.  Since space is a vacuum, this isn't possible.

Confusingly [this scientific video](https://www.ligo.caltech.edu/video/ligo20160211v2) describes "the sound two black holes make when colliding".

Since it's impossible to make sounds in space, this video is actually a *transcription* of sorts from one human sense to another (audio).  I want to underscore that this is a false transcription, and merely:

- Only a mapping of the unseen to what our senses can appreciate
- Constrained by the limits of technology in conveying this information.  Video was used to show a chart.  Audio was used to help understand this.

I'm hoping there is a cognitive word to describe the concept of

- an accurate mapping of information (such as sheet music)

versus

- a simulation/flawed representation that requires context. (e.g. "What does gravity taste like?" is no different than asking "what does gravity sound like?")

Comment: Note to self: `encoding` with a loss of `fidelity/resolution` might be one way of explaining this, but doesn't seem to fit with everyday English.

Comment: Not an answer, but... NB first sentence: *"Gravitational waves sent out from a pair of colliding black holes have been converted to sound waves..."* and that this site works with CalTech and MIT. That's a bit like arguing with Shakespeare about English. If the gravitational waves were close enough to affect our atmosphere, we might well hear them. Also, sounds are picked up from space (presumably a vacuum) all the time, hence SETI.

Comment: This sounds like conversion/translation vs metaphor (all with their broader senses).

Comment: For converting infrared or other non-visible frequencies to our visible spectrum, the standard term is "false color".  But you're looking for something broader than that, I take it.

Comment: The true reason I'm looking for a word is so I can research and compare human learning versus artificial Intelligence & learning.  My concept is that all learning and information gathering is placed into one of two buckets: Abstract vs Concrete. This is abstract learning that is conveyed (smartly) into concrete learning via an audio file. My goal is to make my AI intentions more clear to readers and help me design the robot's organization of information. (/cc @medica for clarification of my intention)

Comment: The usual term for this is *visualisation*. Whether it is used when making things audible, I couldn't say.

Comment: @LamonteCristo given what you've just posted in comments, perhaps you should go to the philosophy SE site.  You've described a classic issue in epistemology (the theory of knowledge)

Comment: It is possible that the author used the word "sound" because the  frequencies are in the same range than audio frequencies. Even if wavelength was not the trigger, using the verb "sounds" is a catchy expression, a "*figure of speech*".

Comment: For audio, I've seen the idea of *visualization* expressed as *audio visualization*. // Note that when a jazz solo is notated on the page, that is called a *transcription*.

Comment: As I noted in my answer, this is _not_ a false transcription. LIGO's detectors converted gravitational waves, which they converted into electrical impulses; these **same** electrical impulses were played back through audio gear **without changing their frequency** (in the first example) to create the 'sound' of the black hole collision. This is a _direct_ transcription -- same notes (frequencies), different instruments (spacetime vs the air between your headphones/speakers and your ears).

Comment: The popular misconception is the opposite of what you claim, that is, the misconception is that sound *does not* travel through (interstellar, interplanetary) space. An atmosphere exists in space, although it's thin. See [Voyager 1 Probe Captures 1st-Ever Sounds of Interstellar Space](http://www.space.com/22781-voyager-1-interstellar-space-sounds-video.html).

Answer (score 1):

The accepted term for transforming *information* (usually in the form of a *signal* - such as *video* or *audio*) from one medium to another is ***transcode***.

> **transcode** - convert (language or information) from one form of coded representation to another.

*Transcoding* implies that the *waveform* of the original signal is preserved (possibly with some distortions) during the transfer to the target medium.

---

Note that it is not possible to map information as perceived by one human sense (e.g. vision) to a format that will by perceived by another sense (e.g. hearing) without taking some *very* extensive creative license.

You can only sense one sound wave at any given moment (or two, if we take into account both ears), and the frequency of that wave cannot exceed 20 kHz. Your eyes, on the other hand, can sense many colors simultaneously and the wave frequencies required to express this information are several orders of magnitude higher.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is the concept of "OVERLAY" or "SUPERIMPOSE"

For instance you take a natural light picture of the Mona Lisa and then take a near-infrared and lay one over the other to look for changes or anamolies.

Great techniques to find differences that the human eye cannot process.

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/overlay

Comment: Trolls everywhere these days. Great that you don't like my answer, too bad you don't take the time to explain why you disagree.

Comment: I don’t think this is correct. OP is asking about a transfer function that maps “the unseen” to “the seen” for the purposes of visualization but does not suggest doing any kind of superposition.

Answer (score 0):

I remember in a philosophy of mind class, we used to use the word/concept "[isomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism)." The idea in philosophy comes from the mathematical definition, which (roughly speaking) requires a two-way mapping between models.

Comment: (+1) *isomorphism* is used in information theory, too. But it describes a quality of the transformation, not the transformation process itself.

Answer (score -1):

You could apply the term *[transmux](https://www.wowza.com/glossary/transmux)* (transcode-multiplexing) to this case.

> Transmux (Transcode-Multiplexing) is a process that changes the format
>   of an audio or video while keeping some or all of the
>   streams containing information from the original. Transmuxing converts
>   to a different container format without changing the contents.

[This article](http://www.nature.com/news/gravitational-waves-how-ligo-forged-the-path-to-victory-1.19382) on LIGO in *Nature* notes:

> Although the two black holes had probably been orbiting each other for
>   millions of years, LIGO began to pick up their waves only when they
>   reached a frequency of 35 cycles per second (hertz). The frequency
>   rapidly increased to 250 hertz.

Those frequencies (35 Hz to 250 Hz) are well within the nominal range of human hearing (20 Hz to 20 kHz). If there had been a medium present to conduct these vibrations of spacetime to our ears (e.g., Earth's atmosphere, as @medica noted), we could have heard them.

For the LIGO video, the Caltech/MIT/LIGO Lab

- took the signals produced by the vibration of spacetime, and
  converted to electrical impulses by LIGO's detectors, and
- played back those **same** electrical impulses to vibrate the diaphragms
  in your earphones or speakers.

(If you're talking about shifting UV or infrared light to the visible spectrum, that involves *[spectral shifting](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=spectral%20shifting)*, which was not necessary in the case of the LIGO data.)

Based on the preceding, I disagree with the assertion that the video was a *false* transcription; it was, in fact, a *direct* transcription -- same notes, different instruments.

Comment: I believe *transcribe* implies *writing*. You write *notes* (hence your Bach example is apt), but you do not write *sounds*.

Comment: @michael.hor257k That's probably a bit narrow, since _transcribe_ also means _record_. But I found what I think might be a better word.

Comment: *Transcribe* means *record* only in the sense that the information is transformed into a **written** form. For example, a *court transcript* is a written record of the oral proceedings. -- WRT to *transmux*, I believe the term is only applicable to [multiplexed signals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplexing) and not here.